# Converting from lower to upper case in Sql Editor in Data Studio

Tags: db2, db2-luw, ibm-data-studio

What keyboard shortcut can I use to switch from lower to upper case and upper to lower case in `Sql Editor` in `Data Studio LUW` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can discover all the keybaord-shortcuts in Data Studio by using menu Help > Active Key Bindings.  This is valid for Data Studio version 4.1.3 and maybe some older versions. You can also use CTRL+SHIFT+L to open the same list of active key bindings.  The active key bindings is a long list, and can depend on which tool you are using in Data Studio.

The shortcut keys depend on your operating-system (e.g. Mac Os, Linux, Windows).

For Linux X64, in the SQL-editor, to convert selected text to uppercase is Shift+Ctrl+X - works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, you wanted it.
If you apply the format to your code, all keywords will be in lowercase.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Lym.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by entailing explanations and how to solve the issue instead of just posting a screenhot.